# react-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'prop.slice')

Tags: react-native

im new to coding, and React-Native, and running into this error which i can't find an answer to, after extensive googling (it might be due to my newbiness and not understanding answers given to other users, so please be patient and point me in the right direction, if thats the case)

the error is:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'timeAsProp.slice')

so to explain what **timeAsProp.slice** is: basically i needed the time to be passed as a prop to the **newOrder()** method, in just two digits. if the time is **10:00:00**, my newOrder method should just proccess: **10**

the current time is stored in state.

```
currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
```

the above current time state reads out on the emulator as:

> 12:00:00 //if the time was 12:00 ocklock

The function

> newOrder(timeAsProp)

recieves the time, and depending on what the hour is, should return a different array of images to be rendered for each hour on the hour.
(i only put two time options hardcoded into the app as im still building it. afterwards there will be a seperate image order returned, for each hour. its hardcoded this way, with a seperate option for each hour, untill i can figure out how to have a loop automatically set the images in their proper order depending on the time)

so basically, i need a different way of doing this, or figuring out why im getting this error...

thnks in advance ;)

heres my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import AwesomeButton from 'react-native-awesome-button';
import Style from './Style';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            currentTime: null,
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
      setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString()
        });
      }, 1000);
    }
    handleButtonPress() {

    }

    **// heres the timeAsProp.slice which is giving me the error:**

    newOrder(timeAsProp) {
        const hour = timeAsProp.slice(0, 2);
        if (hour === '19') {
            return [
           <div>     
            <Image source={require('./img/hey2.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/vav.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/hey1.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/yud.png')} style={Style.image} />
          </div>  
            ];  
        }
        if (hour === '20') {
            return [
           <div>     
            <Image source={require('./img/vav.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/hey2.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/hey1.png')} style={Style.image} />
            <Image source={require('./img/yud.png')} style={Style.image} />
           </div>  
            ];
        }
    }

render() {
    return (
        <View style={Style.rootContainer}>
            <View style={Style.headerContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.blue}> {this.state.curentTime} </Text> 
            </View>
            <View style={Style.displayContainer}>

                 **//this is whats calling newOrder and returning the images**

                 {this.newOrder(this.state.time)}
            </View>
            <View style={Style.buttonContainer} >
                <AwesomeButton
                    states={{
                        default: {
                            text: 'DeeDee! Dont press da button!',
                            backgroundStyle: {
                                backgroundColor: 'blue',
                                minHeight: 45,
                                alignItems: 'center',
                                borderRadius: 30,
                                marginBottom: 15,
                                marginLeft: 15,
                            },
                            onPress: this.handleButtonPress
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
    );
   }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  blue: {
    fontFamily: 'serif',  
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  }
});

export default App;
```

Thanks for taking a look and hopefully teaching me something new!
sb

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to change

```
{this.newOrder(this.state.time)}
```

To

```
{this.newOrder(this.state.currentTime)}
```

Then, in your constructor, initialize currentTime

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        currentTime: new Date().toLocaleTimeString(),
    };
}
```

The reason is that, as stated in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html), render() executes before componentDidMount(), so in the moment newOrder is being called, currentTime has not been initialized.

Comment: ive changed it to:

`{this.newOrder(this.state.currentTime)}`

but now i get this message at runtime:

`"null is not an object (evaluating 'timeAsProp.slice')"`

im assuming this has to do with initial state being set to: `currentTime: null`, since that is essentially whats getting passed into the function.
however the state is supposed to be getting updated each second so i would think that it shouldnt be null...

Comment: @SimchaBinyaminKatsof You should initialize the state in the constructor, because by the moment render first executes, currentTime is still null. I edited my answer and linked to the docs to show the component lifecycle. Hope it helps!

Comment: i've done both of these steps already, however im now getting a new error:
Expected a component class, got [object Object]
ive been googling this for the past hour to no avail.
btw, thnks for all the answers!

Comment: never mind,got that last error worked out.
thnks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

`{this.newOrder(this.state.time)}` is what you're calling in the render method but the value you have in state is `currentTime`:

`this.state = { 
  currentTime: null,
};`

Make sure you're passing the right variable in to the method you're calling. Also, it's better to check in the method that the variable has the type and value you expect before using it. So inside of `newOrder` perhaps check if `timeAsProp` is type string (`typeof timeAsProp === 'string'`) before calling `slice` on it.

Comment: so what you're saying is that i'm passing null into the method, since my currentTime is currently 'null' when the app starts up?
 I fixed the `this.newOrder` to be: `{this.newOrder(this.state.currentTime)}` but im getting the error of `"null is not an object, evaluating 'timeAsProp.slice'"`, as i wrote in my reply to the other answer above from @BenjaminDiaz...